# What are those Image Comics?

Tags: comics, character-identification, image-comics

I just got a newsletter from Image Comics saying [there'll be a dance party](https://imagecomics.com/content/view/image-comics-celebrates-25th-anniversary-with-rccc-homecoming-dance) somewhere. Sadly, I can't attend because I have exams, but the attached image drew my attention:

[image]

I was able to recognise *Spawn* and *Witchblade* (probably) in bottom left corner, but **what are the other characters on this image, and from what comics are they?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know all of them, but here's most and others can feel free to edit in the rest as needed. Clockwise from top left:

[image]

1. Maika from *Monstress*
2. Kamau Kogo and Penny Rolle from *Bitch Planet*
3. Bonnie Black from *Reborn*
4. Shadowhawk (from, duh, *Shadowhawk*)
5. Tim-21 from *Descender*
6. Crow from *East of West*
7. The God of Whispers from *Seven to Eternity*
8. Suzie from *Sex Criminals*
9. Domino Swift from *Motor Crush*
10. Shaft from *Youngblood*
11. Tony Chu from *Chew*
12. *Witchblade* (though which wielder of the titular weapon, I have no idea)
13. Spawn
14. Savage Dragon
15. Marco and Alana from *Saga*
16. *The Walking Dead* (I don't think that's Rick but I'm not sure)

Comment: Thanks for those, and pardon my awful numbers (I'll change in a moment). And thank you @Hesperus!

Comment: New picture is much clearer, nice job!